# Match email addresses with special characters

Tags: regex, perl

I have some .yml files some of which contain email addresses inside them along with other data. I'm trying to find out the email addresses which contain any of these characters `!@#$%^&*()_-+{}`

For example `chankey!007@testserver.com`. These might or might not be invalid addresses. I just need to grab data before `@` which contains mentioned special characters. I tried the below but did not get expected results.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

open (my $out, ">", 'output.txt') or die $!;

find(sub {
  if (-f and /\.yml$/) {
    my $data;
    {
      local $/=undef;
      open my $file, "<", $_ or die "Couldn't open file: $!";
      $data = <$file>;
      close $file;
    }
    if ($data =~ /([a-zA-z0-9+.$#_-]+)@/g){
        my $data = $1;
        if ($data =~ /[+.$#_-]/g){
            print $out "File: $_\n";        
            print $out $data."\n";
        }

    }
  }
}, '.');
```

Comment: Character class can match any of these `print "!" =~ / [!@#$%^&*()_{}+-] /x`

Comment: Note that virtually any character is allowed in email addresses, and that most of those you mentioned are allowed unquoted.   (`#`, `-`, `_`, `~`, `!`, `$`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `;`, `=`, and `:` are allowed unquoted, and so is `.` subject to some placement restrictions. We've seen most of those characters used in the wild.)

Answer (score 0):

### [`(^.*[!@#$%^&*()_\-+{}]+.*)@`](https://regex101.com/r/hM9qO9/1)

This will capture the username **only if** it contains any of the special character that you mentioned is in it. You must add the `\g` modifier to match repeatedly. Here's a breakdown of this from regex101.com:

```
1st Capturing group (^.*[!@#$%^&*()_\-+{}]+.*)
    ^ assert position at start of the string
    .* matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    [!@#$%^&*()_\-+{}]+ match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        !@#$%^&*()_ a single character in the list !@#$%^&*()_ literally (case sensitive)
        \- matches the character - literally
        +{} a single character in the list +{} literally
    .* matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
@ matches the character @ literally
g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Comment: Thanks. That's close but it's also matching email addresses enclosed in quotes, see this: https://regex101.com/r/hM9qO9/2.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak In that case, you must specify **exactly** what you're trying to match in your question. Otherwise, it is all just going to be a stab in the dark. I shall update the answer after you do so.

Comment: If you see the link I've shared, that's matching the email address which has no special character in it. So that should be skipped.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak If you are absolutely certain that the emails are enclosed in single quotes without any spaces, use **`'(.*)'`** to isolate all addresses. After that, apply the regex I posted above to check if they meet the required condition.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak **`'(.*[!@#$%^&*()_\-+{}]+.*)@`** This will do it all in one step, however, it will only work for the format that you specified in your link.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

*updated my regex to ONLY capture those addresses if they contains the characters in the class*

Based on the type of data you provided at the regex101 link, something like this may work

```
(\w*[-!@#$%^&*()_+{}]+\w*)@
```

FYI, by putting the `-` as the first character in the character class, the regex engine treats it as a literal character, rather than a character-class range operator. Also, the underscore is already accounted for in `\w` but I left it in to make the regex more explicit.

Additionally, but using `\w` rather than `.+` or `.*` it means we don't match any whitespace, which shouldn't be in an email address anyway.

Comment: Uh, that fails to match `My.Name!@domain.com`, an extremely common email address format with `!` added. You should be using `.` instead of `\w`.

Comment: My answer was based on the example input he provided in the comment to the other answer. This answer is a minimum solution that can be expanded upon to suit his input data as needed.

Comment: What are you talking about? There's no `\w` in the other answer. That was purely your addition, a limitation you decided to add even though it wasn't requested.